# Using specific properties while referencing to schema

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I'm using **swagger 2.0** and I have the following schema(definition) :

```
"User": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "firstName": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "Tom"
        },
        "lastName": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "Hanks"
        },
        "email": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "Tom.Hanks@gmail.com"
        },
        "password": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "azerty@123456"
    }
}
```

and i want to refer to this schema in one of my responses, so i do the following:

```
"responses": {
    "201": {
        "description": "Created.",
        "schema": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/User"
        }
    }
}
```

Until now everything works perfectly, but i don't want to expose the password property in the response schema. is the anyway to choose exactly the properties i want to use from the `User`definition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way. I'd suggest you define 2 types:

- One type for user data without password, let's name it `User`.
- And another type that *inherits* from it and contains additionally a `password` attribute. Let's name it `UserWithCredential`.